# How do I allow Service Broker access to Master Key of database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to set up SqlDependency on my dev system. The db on my system is a few months old production db which I have attached.

When running SqlDependency from ASP.NET application, I see the following error in Event Viewer.

Service Broker needs to access the master key in the database 'MyDb'. Error code:26. The master key has to exist and the service master key encryption is required.

I searched and found,

> When a database is first attached to a new instance of SQL Server, a
>   copy of the Database Master Key (encrypted by the Service Master Key)
>   is not yet stored in the server. You must use the OPEN MASTER KEY
>   statement to decrypt the Database Master Key. Once the Database Master
>   Key has been decrypted, you have the option of enabling automatic
>   decryption in the future by using the ALTER MASTER KEY statement to
>   provision the server with a copy of the Database Master Key encrypted
>   with the Service Master Key. This option is discussed in ALTER MASTER
>   KEY (Transact-SQL).

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174433(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174433%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

However, it is not very clear what password should I use for the OPEN MASTER KEY statement and from where would I get it? I used the Key_GUID value taken from sys.symmetric_keys from both the machines but got an error "Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Cannot find the symmetric key 'master key', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Database Master Key was created a password was supplied to [CREATE MASTER KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174382%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) it's this password which is required.  If this password is not available to the developers then recreating the encrypted objects losing the currently protected data is the only option.